# winform TableLayoutPanel have some rows, but only one of them is visiable

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

In a winform project, there is  a TableLayoutPanel(TLP), but something is wrong: this TLP has some rows, but onle one row is visiable, it look likes that this TLP has only one row.
To make a comparison, I create a new TLP, and this one works fine: add N rows, it shows N rows. 
I compare these two TLPs, verify their properties， all the same.

Here are the images(I don't have enough reputation to post images, so put my blog(Chinese) link here):
https://blog.csdn.net/zhouyingge1104/article/details/91491476

Has anyone ever encountered the sample problem?

Comment: Please show the code that creates and displays the TLP

Comment: Maybe there's a docked Control inside the TLP (with the same background color) and the Control's `RowSpan` property has been set to `4` and `Margin.All = 0`.

Comment: I moved this TLP to another form, in that form, the bug disappeared, and then moved it back to the original form, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved this TLP to another form, in that form, the bug disappeared, and then moved it back to the original form, it works fine. Seems like a bug of Visual Studio 2010 ?